# I need to enable foreign key checks on table

Tags: magento-1.9, database, admin, category

I manually import category table but after impport there is no connection between table entries thats why categories in admin does not show whole data.how can i enable or make these checks or links.

[image]

Comment: you did manually entry in database for categories?

Comment: Yes i add tables manually

Comment: in which tables you mad entries?

Comment: i add catalog_category_entity,catalog_category_entity_int,catalog_category_entity_varchar, catalog_category_entity_text

Comment: I would suggest you to make an entry for a category from admin and then check which tables get populated and after that you can compare what mistake you have done with your manually entities.